# How to create a custom validator for file upload which accepts image files in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: file-upload

I am using asp.net mvc3.
I am using dataannotation and Jquery unobstrusive for server side and client side validation.
How to validate fileupload which accepts only image file extensions.Need to work exactly same as others.
Do I need to create a custom validator for server side and client side?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using any third party controls for fileupload or else just using `<input type=file`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:
If u are using property in model

public class ValidateFileAttribute : ValidationAttribute
        {
            public override bool IsValid(object value)
            {
                int MaxContentLength = 1 * 1024 * 700; //3 MB
                string[] AllowedFileExtensions = new string[] { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png", ".pdf" };

```
            var file = value as HttpPostedFileBase;

            if (file == null)
                return false;
            else if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'))))
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Please upload Your image of type: " + string.Join(", ", AllowedFileExtensions);
                return false;
            }
            else if (file.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Your image is too large, maximum allowed size is : " + (MaxContentLength / 1024).ToString() + "MB";
                return false;
            }
            else
                return true;
        }
    }
```